# How do I subtract dates in LWC's JS?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, date

I am developing an LWC. I want to subtract two dates and get the number of days between them so that I can conditionally render HTML based on the result.One of the dates is a field
Here's my current code that's not working. I am getting the output as NaN.

```
let today2 = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
let renewalDate = this.accFields.Renewal_Date__c.value;
let daysFromRenewal = (this.today2 - this.renewalDate) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

**Output:**

today2 = 2023-08-20

renewalDate = 2024-03-09

daysFromRenewal = NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `today2` and `renewalDate` are string, so you're dividing a string by a number, that's why the result is `NaN`.

You should use Date objects and leverage [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method that returns the number of milliseconds for this date since the [epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#the_epoch_timestamps_and_invalid_date) (since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00.000 GMT), then you can divide by the number of millisecond in a day (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), finally, if you want an integer value, you should call [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```js
const today2 = new Date();
const renewalDate = new Date(this.accFields.Renewal_Date__c.value);
const daysFromRenewal = Math.floor((today2.getTime() - renewalDate.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
console.log(daysFromRenewal);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you RubenDG!